# It doesn't increment the position

Tags: javascript, css, events

I have the following code, i want to move a box my pressing arrow(left arrow in this case) but is adding only once to left property. If i press multiple times on the left arrow it remains on the same spot. Can't figure why..

```
const box = document.querySelector('div');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

body.addEventListener('keydown', move);

function move(event) {
    let ddd = event.which || event.keyCode;
    let left = 0;
    box.style.position = 'absolute';
    if(ddd === 37) {
        left += 5;
        box.style.left = left + 'px';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're resetting the value of `left` every time. Store `left` outside of `move` to prevent resetting it.

```
const box = document.querySelector('div');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
let left = 0;

body.addEventListener('keydown', move);

function move(event) {
    let ddd = event.which || event.keyCode;
    box.style.position = 'absolute';
    if(ddd === 37) {
        left += 5;
        box.style.left = left + 'px';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time, was looking on google still didn't find the correct answer. I am trying to make a pokemon game and i want to move the character with arrows.

Comment: @GrecA Cool! I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your game!